# XSharedPreferences always get default value in my xposed module

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, xposed

I tried many different ways but still not working.
 Always get default values.

```
    public class HookTest implements IXposedHookLoadPackage  {
        private XSharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        private final static String modulePackageName = HookTest.class.getPackage().getName();

        public void handleLoadPackage(final XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
            this.sharedPreferences = new XSharedPreferences(modulePackageName, "Values");
            sharedPreferences.makeWorldReadable();
            sharedPreferences.reload();
            XposedBridge.log("Xposed_test value: " +sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isRunning", false));
        }
}
```

i tried in MainActivity it's work fine

it's returen correct value

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("Values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(""+pref.getBoolean("isRunning", false));
            if(pref.getBoolean("isRunning", false)==true) {
                setVlaue(MainActivity.this, false);
            }else {
                setVlaue(MainActivity.this, true);
            }
        }
    });
}
public void setVlaue(Context context,boolean isRunning) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.MyReceiver");
    intent.putExtra("isRunning", isRunning);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: handleLoadPackage is usually called before the app starts, therefore when you read  `isRunning` that app has not started yet. Depending on when the app writes this value it would be plausible to only read `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting right permissions to files (`chmod +r shared_prefs shared_prefs/your_prefrences.xml`) helps in most cases. But it isn't good trick.

Good solution is [RemotePreferences](https://github.com/apsun/RemotePreferences.) that uses ContentProvider to access your prefs